# had to change the isInput method slightly to submit files in ie8

Tags: fine-uploader

In order for me to select files in ie8 I had to make the second statement of the isInput function an if instead of an else if.

```
qq.isInput = function(maybeInput) {
    if (window.HTMLInputElement) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(maybeInput) === '[object HTMLInputElement]') {
            if (maybeInput.type && maybeInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'file') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    //else if (maybeInput.tagName) {
    if (maybeInput.tagName) {
        if (maybeInput.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
            if (maybeInput.type && maybeInput.type.toLowerCase() === 'file') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Does this change make sense? or will it break something else?

When I was debugging the javascript in ie8 the function was succeeding the "window.HTMLInputElement" check but was failing the "Object.prototype.toString.call(maybeInput) === '[object HTMLInputElement]'" check.

IE8 WIN XP SP3

Comment: Please open up a bug report.  This looks like a regression in Fine Uploader 3.6.  You can open up a bug report at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new.  I will make fixing this a top priority today.

Comment: ...regression as of 3.6.1, by the way.

Comment: Bug can be tracked at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/876.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 3.6.3 hotfix release just went live that addresses [this issue](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/876).

This was yet another regression created when I modified the code to handle environments that involve multiple windows.

Fine Uploader was broken in IE8 specifically due to some (IMHO) sound logic that is not followed by IE8.  `qq.isInput` first checks if the `window` has a concept of the `HTMLInputElement` "interface".  If it does, it expects any input element will have a value of "[object HTMLInputElement]" when calling `toString` on the parameter (using `Object.prototype.toString`).  Obviously, IE8 doesn't subscribe to this logic, as the value is "[object Object]".

The same faulty/inconsistent logic is present in IE7 (when calling `toString` on a host object), but this particular issue is not a problem in IE7 since IE7 does not expose the `HTMLInputElement` "interface" and, therefore, we skip right over to the next check which looks a bit closer at the potential host object in an attempt to identify it as an input element in the absence of the existence of the `HTMLInputElement` interface.